# VSCode on Windows for Remote SSH

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh, vscode-remote

Am trying to use Remote SSH to connect to a Raspberry Pi 4 from my Windows VSCode installation.

My Windows VSCode version info:

```
Version: 1.63.0 (system setup)
Commit: 7db1a2b88f7557e0a43fec75b6ba7e50b3e9f77e
Date: 2021-12-07T06:26:56.179Z
Electron: 13.5.2
Chromium: 91.0.4472.164
Node.js: 14.16.0
V8: 9.1.269.39-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19043
```

For a brief period, I need to access my RPi from outside my home network. I configured port forwarding on my router, coupled with a DDNS entry to route traffic from the web through port 8090 to port 22 on the RPi's local LAN IP. NOTE, I have previously used port forwarding extensively to access all manner of devices from outside my home network, so am confident that my router configuration is correct.

Here is my config file:

```
Host XX.YY.org:8090
  HostName XX.YY.org:8090
  User pi

Host 192.168.0.4
  HostName 192.168.0.4
  User pi
```

Using the IP address locally works as expected - I am prompted for the password for the user "pi".
However, the DNS form doesn't work as expected - instead of being prompted for the password of the user "pi", I am prompted for the Windows user I am logged-in as.  This behavior is consistent and repeatable.

I opened a PuTTY session configured to "XX.YY.org", with port 8090 instead of the usual 22, and I get connected to the Raspberry Pi just fine and able to enter the user and password.

Incidentally, if I try to use a Windows CMD prompt and "ssh pi@XX.YY.org -p 8090" I am also able to connect as expected.

Now, I suppose I can live with (for that brief period) using PuTTY instead of VS Code, but that'll force me to use vi or something like that on the RPi...

I tried wiping the ssh config file and re-adding a new entry (or what I think is a new entry!), but through VSCode, I ALWAYS get prompted for the password of tghe local WIndows user instead of the Raspberry Pi user "pi".

If there are any suggestions to overcome this, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Regards...

Comment: Just an added observation... If I use Windows CMD prompt and type in "ssh XX.YY.org -p 8090" I get the problem that I get with VSCode, i,e I am prompted to enter the password of my WIndows Login...

Answer (score 0):

After "Remote-SHH: Connect to host...", you will see the dialogue box "Select configured SSH host or enter user@host". At this point, do not select the host name or IP address added previously but you should enter 'pi@192.168.0.4'. In this way VS Code will not use the local windows user name for the SSH connection.